# get image from previous controller

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

i am getting a picture from the iPhone's camera in one nib file (getPhoto.xib), where I save it into the camera library and also display it in an UIImageView (image1). Then, I have a next button which loads a different nib file (naming.nib) where the user can add a name for the image. How I can access the image from the first nib file so that I can display it in an `UIImageView` (image2) in the second nib file?

I'm trying the following, but nothing is displayed in image2:

```
UIImageView *image2= [[UIImageView alloc initWithImage:
    [UIImageView imageNamed:image1]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [`imageNamed`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed:): method requires an `NSString` argument. Assuming that the name of `image1` is actually "image1", you would do:

```
UIImageView *image2 = [[UIImageView alloc]
             initWithImage:[UIImageView imageNamed:@"image1"]];
```

Note that the "name" here is the name you used when saving the image to the camera library.

Answer (score 0):

call retain on image1 (the one you get from camera) and use it where ever u are currently trying to use image2